# Emacs shell send ^] (hat-right-sqare-bracket)

Tags: shell, escape

Trying to run `telnet` in Emacs shell I cannot figure out how to send `^]` to terminate it.

Comment: I think you can terminate with `C-c C-c`.

Comment: @caisah nope, that doesn't work, neither does `C-c C-z`.

Comment: You should be able to press `C-q C-]`

Comment: @JulesTamagnan and yes indeed. You can make it an answer, if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to press  <kbd>C-q</kbd>  to run `quoted-insert` to insert any key chord you want. So pressing  <kbd>C-q C-]</kbd>  will insert `^]` into the buffer instead of running the command bound to  <kbd>C-]</kbd>