# how to insert tab while in iedit-mode

Tags: iedit

How to insert `<TAB>` while in iedit mode?

following example:

```
int blah; //< x
float moo; //< y
void foobar; //< z
```

Now I select '//<' and go into iedit-mode, because I want to align those comments nicely with a single tab character. I'd like to get following result:

```
int blah;   //< x
float moo;  //< y
void foobar;    //< z
```

*It doesn't look good here on stackexchange, because of wrong tab width.*

Anyway, when in `iedit-mode` `<tab>` and `S-<tab>` switches to next/previous occurence.

**Edit:** Duplicate of [question to Emacs shell and telnet](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23807/emacs-shell-send-hat-right-sqare-bracket)? This question is solved by the same solution. But I would have never searched for that to solve my iedit problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emacs shell send ^\] (hat-right-sqare-bracket)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23807/emacs-shell-send-hat-right-sqare-bracket)

Comment: The solution is the same but I would had never looked at that question.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Someone should maybe do some cleanup editing, so the question fits what it is really asking (or should be asking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `quoted-insert`, bound to `C-q` by default.  It'll insert the next key literally, without triggering any other functions bound to that key.

So you'd say `C-q TAB` to get what you want.